In Virtual Box Ubuntu VM Network Settings Selecting attached to NAT
Good Day,
Connecting my local host (Win11) Forinet VPN client to a specific network I can ping Management IP's on that network via my local host Command Prompt, however I cannot ping these remote IP's via Ubuntu CLI.
In Virtual Box Ubuntu VM Network Settings Selecting attached to NAT, I then can ping via the VPN connection, again however the NAT assigns a 10.0.2.15 IP to Ubuntu which my local host cannot ping.
Where do I assign a static route to be able to reach the NAT IP?
Local Win11?, Local Router? Ubuntu? and how?
Any feedback will be appreciated
Regards

In my configuration I have:

Windows 11 Ethernet 2: 10.0.0.196
Windows 11 Ethernet 3: 192.168.56.11
Ubuntu 22.04.5: 10.0.2.15 Virtualbox Adaptor 1 (NAT)
Ubuntu 22.04.5: 192.168.56.102 Virtualbox Adaptor 2 (HOST-ONLY)

I can ping from Windows 11 into Ubuntu using the 192.168.56.102 addr
I can also RDP from Windows 11 into Ubuntu using the 192.168.56.102 addr
I'm sure if I decided to do SMB from Ubuntu, the IP addr would come into play, but instead of SMB, I used the Virtualbox share drive feature, and I mount the share drive from Ubuntu.
Is this what you are trying to make happen on your LAN?
